Thriller movie with weird town and disappearances
I'm look for a movie around 1995-2008. I think from memory the lead was a woman and there was a sheriff of the town.
There would start to be disappearances in the town. But then those people who disappeared would reappear again after a couple of days being very weird and strange. And it would start happening with everyone in the town one by one.
All I remember in the end is that the lead and the sheriff follow a group and see some kind of ritual where a person is lead into a river and disappears. Then another person appears who looks exactly the same and the movie ends. I vaguely remember it was about some kind of alien invasion/abduction.

What language was it in.?  Where was it set? Can you describe the actors?

It was in English. In a town in the USA. Both are white and the female was blonde. That's all I can remember unfortunately.

Could you be thinking of the 2005 TV series Invasion? The general plot sounds pretty similar.

Yes the premise is very close. Don't think so though. The Invasion looks more action oriented and I would have remembered Nicole Kidman. The movie was showing on Star Movies channel about 5-12 years ago.

@Fai: user52062 is talking about the TV series, not the movie. Follow his link in his answer. It sounds pretty close.
